# Can Aladdin wish for unlimited wishes?

Tags: plot-explanation, aladdin

Okay I saw the Disney movie Aladdin today but my question is if the genie granted the boy unlimited rule free wishes.

Could he wish for anything and whatever he wants? if it’s rule free unlimited wishes could anything I mean anything he desires happen in a blink of a eye

Comment: Didn't Genie explicitly state that you cannot wish for more wishes (along with raising the dead or make people fall in love)?

Comment: @HorusKol Yes.  Exactly.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: maybe this reddit thread can help: https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/3u6x5k/aladdin_genies_3_rules/?st=jctrgtdt&sh=24d7463e

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, why does this question require the Aladdin world? Couldn't it abstractly be applied to every genie in a bottle concept? I don't know any of them where a valid wish wasn't immediately granted.

Answer (score 13):

- **Can Alladin wish for unlimited wishes?**

Well from the movie, Genie boy forbids Aladdin from wishing for more genies or wishes and so that's a moot point... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

- **If Aladdin wishes for unlimited wishes, can he wish for anything?**

There is a hiccup in that too since there are 3 rules that the genie follows which are:

1. Cannot kill anybody
2. Cannot make him fall in love
3. Cannot revive dead people (though that's debatable)

- **If the genie granted the boy unlimited rule-free wishes:**

*You answered it yourself.*

If there are no rules and wishes are unlimited, he could wish for anything he ever wanted. And that's opinion based since we can't determine what Aladdin wants... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: OP's confusion might stem from the Genie's phrasing: IIRC his exact words are "Ix-nay on the wishing for more wishes". "Ix-nay" is pig-Latin slang for "no", but if you're not familiar with pig-Latin it just sounds like gibberish.

Comment: Number 2 is actually "Can't make anyone fall in love with you".  i.e.: Genie cannot force others to love Aladdin.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Technically, "Ix-nay" is Pig Latin for "Nix".  Webster's Dictionary defines "nix" as "Put an end to; Cancel".  So, while they're similar, "Ix-nay" is actually closer to "stop" or "don't" than "no".  But that's all semantics.

Answer (score 2):

No, because of the rule that states no wishing for more wishes. He can't wish for more wishes, rule free or otherwise. If the rule didn't exist, then still no because the one where genie said he didn't bring people back from the dead, wasn't actually a rule, it was just genie's personal preference not to bring people back from the dead ''because it's icky'' which basically shows that there are some wishes he won't do, which kinda doesn't make sense with what Jafar wishes for.

If the genie has rules, then why not have one stating, you can't wish for infinite power, or anything evil, but nope, that's ok, as long as there's no murder, no luuuurve, and no pet cemetery sequels, anything else is a.o.k.

But at the end of the day, it's a cartoon made for fun that's not really supposed to be as closely scrutinised as this. It's a fantasy, so it doesn't have to make sense, and the wishes aren't the point of the story. The point is that, even someone who grows up in the slums, has more chance of fulfilling their greatest wishes, without the help of a genie, just by being themselves. As Aladdin's wishes kinda made things worse for him (except for setting genie fee, but that was a wish for genie, not for Aladdin) and it was only when he showed his true self to Jasmine, that he got his real wishes come true. Disney, bringing you life lessons since Mickey could whistle.